# Why add the number 1 to find the median number

Tags: statistics, median

Example 1: There are 45 numbers

- 45 plus 1 is 46, then divide by 2 and you get 23
- So the median is the
  23rd number in the sorted list.

Example2: There are 66 numbers

- 66 plus 1 is 67, then divide by 2 and you get 33.5 33 and a half?
  That means that the 33rd and 34th numbers in the sorted list are the
  two middle numbers.
- So to find the median: add the 33rd and 34th numbers together and divide by 2

Why do we have to add the number 1 regardless to find the median ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ objects, labeled $1,\ldots,n$.

If $n$ is odd, then the middle one is $\frac{n+1}{2}$. For example,

$$\fbox{1}\fbox{2}\fbox{3}\fbox{4}\fbox{5}\\
\overset{\uparrow}{\tfrac{5+1}{2}}$$

If $n$ is even, then there is no "middle" one, but the ones closest to the middle are $\frac{n}{2}$ and $\frac{n}{2}+1$.
$$\fbox{1}\fbox{2}\fbox{3}\fbox{4}\fbox{5}\fbox{6}\\
\;\;\;\overset{\uparrow}{\tfrac{6}{2}}\overset{\uparrow}{\small(\tfrac{6}{2}+1)}$$
Those are the integers that are closest to $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

**In general**, if we consider the interval of real numbers $[1,x]$, the point that's equidistant from the ends (otherwise known as the middle) is the point $m$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
\underbrace{m-1}_{\text{distance from $m$ to $1$}}&=\underbrace{x-m}_{\text{distance from $x$ to $m$}}\\\\
2m&=x+1\\\\
m&=\frac{x+1}{2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That equation really clarified it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you started counting from $1$.  Given a range of numbers from $1$ to $n$, the midpoint is $\frac {1+n}2$